# How to write data to provide/inject asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a page on which data is initialized via async fetch:

```js
async fetch() {
    const res = await requestApi(this, '/database');
    this.sliderData = res.homeSlider;
    this.modelData = res.model;
    ... 
}
```

Then this data is thrown into the child components through the props, but since there are child components of level 3-4, it becomes not convenient to use the props with page. Is it possible to use provide/inject in this case? Moreover, it is important that the transmitted data is reactive. Objects always come from the request when trying to use provide/inject:

```js
provide() {
    return {
        sliderData: this.sliderData
    };
}
```

The data did not have time to be initialized and an empty object was sent.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is the best idea, but you can add a variable (for example `isLoading: true`) to your data; when all data you need is loaded change `this.isLoading = false`; additionally, add `v-if="!isLoading"` to the parent component. In this case, your child component will inject already loaded `sliderData`.